# Why is my simulation not finding infinite expected value?

Tags: java, math, random, probability

In the Youtube video [Numberphile Infinity](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDl7g_2x74Q) (starting at 6:09) there is an experiment described (the [St. Petersburg Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox)) in which a game has infinite expected value.

I tried to write a Java program to find out a long-run expected value (average). The theoretical expectation is infinity, but what I get is some numbers around 10. Is it because my program is wrong? Because I think when the number of experiment is large enough, the experimental average will be very close to the mathematical expectation.
Here is my program.

```
public class Main {
    public static final int NUM_EXPERIMENT = 1000000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EXPERIMENT; i++) {
            int counter = 1;
            int subtotal = 1;
            while ((int) (Math.random() * 2) == 0) {
                subtotal *= 2;
                counter++;
            }
            total += subtotal;
        }
        double expectation = total / (double) NUM_EXPERIMENT;
        System.out.println("The expectation of this experiment is " + expectation);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int` will wrap around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this has everything to do with math and little to do with `int`s.

One thing you might notice is that if you run more and more trials, the expected value will get larger and larger.  The expected value is infinite because there are extraordinarily unlikely events that yield extraordinarily large payoffs.  You're unlikely to get this to happen because the probability of earning 2<sup>n</sup> profit is 2<sup>-n</sup>.  For example, this means that the probability of getting $1,000,000 (approximately $2<sup>20</sup>) is about 1 in 2<sup>20</sup>.  On expectation, you'd need to run one million trials before you ever see this occur.  Consequently, if you only run one hundred thousand trials, you wouldn't expect to see something like this happen.  However, as the number of trials increases, the probability that you hit one of these sorts of sequences grows, and so the expected value will increase.

Think of it this way: you will never, ever see infinite profit because *eventually* the coin tosses the wrong way and you collect your winnings.  Therefore, you won't ever get infinite profit reported by your program.  However, as you play more and more games, the average will increase.  The [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) does indeed say that as you play more games you'll approach the average more and more closely, but it doesn't say that a small number of trials will suffice.  Since your expected value is infinite, you're going to need a *lot* of trials before you're going to converge to infinity. ^_^

Other answers have noted that you might be overflowing the maximum value of an `int`, which is true but I think irrelevant here.  You should switch to using something like a `double` or `long` to hold the values, but the reason you're not seeing infinite payout is because it's exponentially unlikely that you'll see one of the sequences that yields extreme payouts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: BigInteger can be used here - in case of error it will throw `OutOfMemory...`

Comment: The average income grows logarithmically with time. I did some simulations, http://sdrv.ms/180eSjz and got apporx income of 10 per game when played 1 mln games. I expect an income of 20 at about 1 to 10 billion games. The [theoretical developments, however, based on Steinhaus Sequence, show](http://www.science20.com/hammock_physicist/statistical_physics_attacks_st_petersburg_paradox_resolved-96549) that I should receive an income of 20 already after playing 2^18 games (i.e. less than million).

Answer (score 1):

You are overflowing the integer data-types. They hit a max value and cycle back to the minimum value. Can't do infinite equations literally like that.

Comment: I don't believe that's the issue here.  See my answer for details.

Comment: @template likely both apply because he's calculating the large number before he multiplies by the odds.

Answer (score 0):

Range of integer value is ~ `-2 147 000 000 to 2 147 000 000`, if you exceed the max value of an integer, it is overflowed to the min value of an integer.